# Unable to get the transition on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am creating a navbar and when I want to add hover effect over links its not working, I want to add transform property to the `after` element of links but its not working.

```
#navbar {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
.link-list {
      display: flex;
      gap: 2rem;
    }
    
.menu-link {
      color: var(--white);
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    
.menu-link::after {   /*this is for the bottom border line which is 25% in length*/
      background: var(--white);
      content: "";
      width: 50%;
      height: 2px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 25%;
      bottom: -4px;
      transform: scaleX(0); /*i am adding transform 0 */
      transform-origin: center;
      transition: transform 500ms ease;
    }
    
.menu-link:hover .menu-link::after{ /* unable to get this effect on hover */
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }
```

Link lists

```
<section class="link-list">
   <a href="#" class="menu-link">About</a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-link">Careers</a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-link">Events</a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-link">Products</a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-link">Explore</a>
</section>
```

Comment: your scale change nothing because it's still 1. you have to put something bigger or smaller than 1 because 1 is a size by default. See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `scale` is size * argument.
`scaleX(0)` will *0 so your element will disappear.
`scaleX(1)` will *1 so your element won't change.
Use the number bigger than 1 or smaller than 1 to do it.

```
#navbar {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
.link-list {
      display: flex;
      gap: 2rem;
    }
    
.menu-link {
      color: var(--white);
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    
.menu-link::after {   /*this is for the bottom border line which is 25% in length*/
      background: var(--white);
      content: "";
      width: 50%;
      height: 2px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 25%;
      bottom: -4px;
      transform: scaleX(0); /*i am adding transform 0 */
      transform-origin: center;
      transition: transform 500ms ease;
    }
    
.menu-link:hover .menu-link::after{ /* unable to get this effect on hover */
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }

        

"<section class="link-list">
              <a href="#" class="menu-link">About</a
              ><a href="#" class="menu-link">Careers</a
              ><a href="#" class="menu-link">Events</a
              ><a href="#" class="menu-link">Products</a
              ><a href="#" class="menu-link">Explore</a>
            </section>"
```

Comment: still not working, it works only when I am add hover over section instead of anchor tags ,, but it show line after all tags at once